# jtds and rjdbc classpath - Error in .jfindClass

Tags: macos, jtds, rjdbc

I am trying to connect to an SQL server using the jtds driver for JDBC connectivity but the JDBC call in RJDC keeps coming back with an error message. I am using R in Mac OSX

'Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found'

I am able to successfully create the connection when I use Microsoft's JDBC driver but for the life of me, I cannot figure out why the classpath to jtds JDBC driver can simply not be found.

The following script call works with the Microsoft JDBC driver
drv <- JDBC("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver","/Library/Java/Extensions/sqljdbc4.jar", "‘")

The jtds call that does not work is
drv <- JDBC("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver","/Library/Java/Extensions/jtds-1.3.0-dist/jtds-1.3.0.jar","‘")

Could someone please shed some light if you are aware of the potential error I am making

Answer (score 0):

Try using jtds-1.2.7 instead. I had exact same problem with jdts-1.3.1 on Linux which disappeared when I switched to 1.2.7.